# Recording video in Flash to a file locally

Tags: flash, apache-flex, video-streaming, webcam

I know that many such questions have been asked before but most of them are outdated to 3 years back. Can someone please help me out with this:

I need to record video from webcam for a duration of  about an hour using flash. One option is that I directly stream it to Server. But just in case, is it possible to record video in Flash without streaming it to a media server like Red5 or Adobe Media Server? I wish to store it locally on a file system.

If possible, I can then transmit the file in chunks to the media server. The intention behind is that: When the user is using it, I do not want to eat all of his bandwidth and he should have rnough bandwidth to be able to browse other sites in parallel (to enrich his experience). I can, in limited duration then stream the buffered part.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is possible with Adobe Air 2.0 but I've not tried myself.
Here are a couple of links that maybe useful to you.
http://www.zeropointnine.com/blog/updated-flv-encoder-alchem/
http://mydevrecords.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/local-recording-in-adobe-air-using-red5.html

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is possible to store the file of your recording. Red5 does that automatically when you tell it through the AS3 script to record. It creates a file inside of the red5 installation directory in webapps/live/[channel name]/yourfile.flv. IUt can only record in flv format not in mp4 like Adobe media server, but it's still useful